# Restoring SQL databases accross environments - custom environment settings design

Tags: .net, sql-server, environment-variables, production-environment

I am busy with implementing a database restore procedure across production/acceptance/testing/development environments and I am trying to decide on what to do with environment specific application settings.

To clarify, those settings are stored in the database since they are attached to a record of some kind. The tables that the settings are stored mainly consist of `ForeignKeyToEntity, Key, Value`

This database needs to be (on regular basis) backed up from a Production environment and restored on an Acceptance/Development and Test environment as part of a standard DTAP procedure. However, the database contains multiple settings which can be environment specific (different values for Production and Acceptance, for example). This limits the migration/restore procedures since I can't use a complete database backup/restore procedure but need to copy specific tables and data.

I have considered the following approaches to be able to completely restore a database:

**1) Store settings in a separate database:**
   This will keep the main database clean and will be able to always restore it fully.

**2) Store settings in a separate database and overwrite settings in main database:**
   This approach requires the least changes to the application but is not as safe (a setting might be forgotten in the separate store leaving the setting in the main database with the value of a different environment).

**3) Separate settings in the main database by environment**
   This approach requires modifications to the settings table by adding an extra environment identifier.

Are there any best practices on this problem? Are there any alternatives? Or which approach from the above makes most sense?